# Google Drive API - how many times a file has been downloaded?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-apps, google-docs-api

I have been trying hard to find any information on how to see how many times a file in Google Drive has been downloaded. I have tried looking into Drive API, Google Activity API and a number of forums, but I can only find info about how to download a file, nowhere about download stats, i.e. number of downloads.

Any suggestions or hints will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**

But you can use [Google URL Shortener](https://goo.gl/) and cut short the **original link** of this file then give the link to your friends; after this you will be able to see how many clicks are clicked at that link. You can also view any other details you need like Countries, Referrers, Browsers, Platforms and more!

Answer (score 0):

At this time (2015-11-07), I don't think there's any way to do this via any Google API. Google's server logs would let you answer this, but I don't believe you can get access to them.

Comment: thanks for the answer @davejagoda, do you know if it is at least possible to check my own downloads (in a sense it might be tricky, but I want to see if a file from Drive appears in my own downloads from Google)?

Comment: That I think you might be able to do - there's data like this: `u'lastViewedByMeDate': u'2014-09-21T23:13:39.943Z'`

Comment: ok, great, but apart from that, are you aware of a way to request all downloaded files?

Comment: I am not sure I understand completely - there's a set of files that you can access from Google drive (I know this can be found by a program). You want to know which files in that set have ever been downloaded (or maybe viewed) by you? Might be good to update the question in case others can help.

Comment: viewed/downloaded is only possible with drive unlimited and only for users in your domain, using special admin drive acrivity reports.

Comment: @ZigMandel does that mean that to be able to view downloade files (assuming I get Drive Unlimited) I will need to create a website, have some files listed there (say with links to my Google Drive) and then I could see how many downloads?